# 'less than or approximately' holds uniformly over set?

Tags: uniform-convergence

I was reading [these notes](http://www.hairer.org/notes/Regularity.pdf) on regularity structures, and came across this (equation 2.5)

> There exists a linear map such that
>   $$\mbox{left hand side } \lesssim \mbox{ right hand side}$$
>   locally uniformly over $x$.

First: what exactly does $\lesssim$ mean?

Second, what does it mean for a bound to hold locally uniformly over $x$? Does it mean that the left hand side converges locally uniformly to the right hand side for every $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)\lesssim g(x)$ if $f(x)\le C g(x)$

"locally uniformly bounded" means what it says. This bound holds uniformly, at least locally.